# SCNCamera xFov, yFov replacement by fieldOfView and focalLength

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, fieldofview

I used to set values of `xFov` and `yFov` of `SCNCamera` to values calculated from camera `field of view` and my view `frame size`. This was working fine in my `AR` engine implementation (with `SceneKit`, not `ARKit`). In new Xcode I see warning, that `xFov` and `yFov` were deprecated and I should use `fieldOfView` and `focalLength` instead. I would like to update my code, but I don't know how to set these variables to correspond exactly to what I used to have. The closest thing is to set `fieldOfView` to value I used before for xFov * 2 - but it's not exactly the same, objects are actually appear a little smaller. Is there some way to calculate these new values to work just like if I set `xFov and yFov` with given values? What I have are these values that I used to have before for `xFov and yFov` so I would like to calculate `fieldOfView` and `focalLength` from it.

This is how I get `xFov` and `yFov` values:

```
private func updateSceneInformation() {
    guard let captureDevice = captureDevice, captureDevice.hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video) else { return }

    let xFov: Double, yFov: Double
    let cameraFieldOfView = Double(captureDevice.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView)
    let videoDimentions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(captureDevice.activeFormat.formatDescription)
    let aspect = Double(videoDimentions.width) / Double(videoDimentions.height)
    let videoSize: CGSize
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait {
        yFov      = cameraFieldOfView
        xFov      = yFov / aspect
        videoSize = CGSize(videoDimensions: videoDimentions).rotated90Degrees
    }
    else {
        xFov      = cameraFieldOfView
        yFov      = xFov / aspect
        videoSize = CGSize(videoDimensions: videoDimentions)
    }
    let aspectSize  = videoSize.aspectFill(fitToSize: bounds.size)
    let originPoint = CGPoint(x: (bounds.width - aspectSize.width) / 2, y: (bounds.height - aspectSize.height) / 2)
    let sceneFrame  = CGRect(origin: originPoint, size: aspectSize)
    let fieldOfView = FOV(horizontal: xFov, vertical: yFov)

    let newSceneInformation = SceneInformation(fieldOfView: fieldOfView, frame: sceneFrame, interfaceOrientation: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation)
    if sceneInformation != newSceneInformation {
        sceneInformation = newSceneInformation
    }
}
```

On iPhone 6s horizontal this gives me

```
SceneInformation(fieldOfView: (58.63214874267578, 32.98058366775513), frame: (0.0, -0.09375, 667.0, 375.1875), interfaceOrientation: .landscapeRight)
```

`Frame` Is the frame of `SCNView`.

And this is how I was applying these values before (which was working as expected)

```
override var sceneInformation: SceneInformation {
    didSet {
        cameraNode.camera?.xFov = Double(sceneInformation.fieldOfView.horizontal)
        cameraNode.camera?.yFov = Double(sceneInformation.fieldOfView.vertical)
        sceneView.frame = sceneInformation.frame
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post actual values for x/yFOV, frame size, fieldOfView, and focalLength. Code wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I added the code and values